# Cold weather and workout outside

Tags: workout

I play football, and I have problem with the cold outside. I mean, what should I do, so I can be more power to cold weather because this air destroys me.

I have problem with the cold weather. Generally I cold easier than others. For example, when weather is cold my body shakes. Another example, when I get to sea in the afternoon I shake much, when I go of the see shake even more.

Comment: What is exact problem? Cold wind can be really bad. Or maybe long breathing cold air? Or - cold itself...

Comment: Cold wind is the problem

Comment: Do you have problems with cold in parts of your body - like ears, or knees? Or maybe problem is with muscles working in that conditions? I'm just trying to understand the problem.

Comment: No ,I have problem with the cold weather.Generally I cold easier than others.Example when weather is cold my body is shake.Another example ,when I get to sea in afternoon I shake much ,when I go of the sea more shake

Comment: Looks like it got closed, so I'll answer here. It can be that you have much less fat then - for instance me. For cold - that is not good, and you need to take care about your body. Corpse is key here. Hands, and legs - only if you feel it is a problem. For instance - in cycling - palms, and knees, are problem since air flow hits there... maybe you have same pattern. Check if you need to take care about head as well. For me - I have to keep ears worm, and it is OK for me, but we all are different.